# Filling values into mutiple dictionaries via for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to use a index or list: vItems = ["Yew","Magic","Maple"]
To populate dictionaries by those names (Yew,Magic,Maple). I have 8 variables that update every loop, and I would like to fill in 8 dictionary items to those 3 dictionaries (24 total). To avoid having 24 lines of code, I'd rather try to integrate a for loop to reduce it to 8 lines. Here is what I have so far:

```
import requests
import bs4
print("Saplings script running...")

#Pulls all GE prices
vUrl = "https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/1h"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Calculating profit/hr methods',
    'From': ''
}
res = requests.get(vUrl , headers = headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
vText = str(res.text)

#vItems = [["Yew",5315,5373],["Magic",5316,5374],["Mahogany",21488,21480],["Maple",5314,5372],["Dragonfruit",22877,22866],["Palm",5289,5502],["Papaya",5288,5501],["Celastrus",22869,22856]]
Yew = {"SeedID":5315,"SaplingID":5373}
Magic = {"SeedID":5316,"SaplingID":5374}
Maple = {"SeedID":5314,"SaplingID":5372}

vItems = ["Yew","Magic","Maple"]

#Searches large string of text for dictionary related to item ID
vStart = vText.index("\"" + str(Yew['SeedID']) + "\"")
vStart = vText.index("{",vStart)
vEnd = vText.index("}",vStart) + 1
vSeed = eval(vText[vStart:vEnd])

#Searches large string of text for dictionary related to item ID
vStart = vText.index("\"" + str(Yew['SaplingID']) + "\"")
vStart = vText.index("{",vStart)
vEnd = vText.index("}",vStart) + 1
vSapling = eval(vText[vStart:vEnd])

# Populates Yew dictionary from values pulled online
vTest = "Yew"
Yew['Seed_avgHighPrice'] = vSeed['avgHighPrice']
Yew['Seed_highPriceVolume'] = vSeed['highPriceVolume']
Yew['Seed_avgLowPrice'] = vSeed['avgLowPrice']
Yew['Seed_lowPriceVolume'] = vSeed['lowPriceVolume']

Yew['Sapling_avgHighPrice'] = vSapling['avgHighPrice']
Yew['Sapling_highPriceVolume'] = vSapling['highPriceVolume']
Yew['Sapling_avgLowPrice'] = vSapling['avgLowPrice']
Yew['Sapling_lowPriceVolume'] = vSapling['lowPriceVolume']

# Prints results
print(Yew)
print(Yew['Seed_avgHighPrice'], Yew['Seed_highPriceVolume'], Yew['Seed_avgLowPrice'], Yew['Seed_lowPriceVolume'])
```

It only populates the data for Yew currently, but I would like to replace the Yew['asdf'] with a for loop. Something like:

```
for k in vItems:
'k'['asdf'] = vSeed['asdf']
```

Comment: theres more then one problem with the `for` loop. look like indentation is the main thing.

Comment: Also what's the `asdf` here for?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

```py
y = ['hello']
z = ['world']

for item in (y, z):
    for e in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
        print(item, e)
```

Output:

```
['hello'] a
['hello'] b
['hello'] c
['world'] a
['world'] b
['world'] c
```

Roughly applied to the particular use case above, that'd look like this:

```py
for prefix, item in (('Seed', vSeed), ('Sapling', vSapling)):
    for key in ('avgHighPrice', 'highPriceVolume', 'avgLowPrice', 'lowPriceVolume'):
        Yew[f'{prefix}_{key}'] = item[key]
```